# Leaving the family business?

Tags: career-switch

I work for a company owned by some of my family members. They offered me a FT job a while back, and truth be told, I didn't really want to accept it because I knew it would probably not be a good fit for me, but a lot of people close to me thought I'd be crazy to decline, and I did not want to look back on turning the offer down as a missed opportunity (plus, I thought it'd be cool to work with my family, despite warnings I received from a few other people that mixing family with business can be risky), so I took them up on the offer.

Fast forward to today, and I realize I made a mistake. The job isn't all bad, but it is simply not the right fit for me. Lesson learned about accepting a job when you already suspect you're not meant for it. I should have gone with my gut instinct, but I can't change the past so no point in kicking myself for it I guess.

I've just grown tired of this typical run of the mill office job, I barely have any motivation to get out of bed in the morning now. The company and work colleagues are actually pretty cool but the job does not suit me. And it's all they have for me there so going to my family and talking to them about it would do no good.

I just feel torn though between wanting to find something else, yet also wishing to keep positive relations with my family intact. They gave me a chance that not many other companies would have and I feel grateful for that, so the last thing I want to do is disappoint them. But if the job isn't working out then what's the use in staying?

I'm curious to know if anyone here has had similar experiences working for family and how you can respectfully move on without burning bridges or feeling guilty?

Answer (score 4):

Just tell them what you told us: Thanks for thinking of you when they were filling the position, but you gave it a try and it just isn't the right job for you.

If you want to be kind, you can negotiate how much notice time they need in order to transfer your work in progress to someone else and to start looking for a replacement... But doing business with family is doing *business* with family and if you just give two weeks notice that's entirely fair.

Yes, you may get guilt-tripped. They will get over it. Or they won't, but that will be their problem and you shouldn't let them make it yours.

Answer (score -1):

Well, we can't do anything about feelings here, and you can't control how your family reacts.

What you can do is be above board with them in your dealings.  Let them know right now that you're having doubts and that you're considering other lines of work.  Make it clear that you're not going to just leave.  Offer to groom your replacement and have him or her onboard before you move on.  When you do move on, make yourself available on your off hours to answer any questions or to just pitch in here and there to help the family.

It wouldn't hurt to stay there part time for a while after you've started in a new position because right now, your perspective is kind of one-sided.  You may find, after a fashion, that you DO want to work for/with your family.  Being as above board now will keep that door open should you ever to wish to go through it again.